# MySQL query - How can I make this example report?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in table like this.

```
+------------+----------------+--------+-------+
| date       | shop_id        | status | count |
+------------+----------------+--------+-------+
| 2016-04-01 | 121101201      | A      |     9 |
| 2016-04-01 | 121101201      | B      |     6 |
| 2016-04-04 | 121101201      | A      |     4 |
| 2016-04-04 | 121101201      | B      |     5 |
| 2016-04-05 | 121101201      | A      |    11 |
| 2016-04-05 | 121101201      | B      |     3 |
```

And I want to make query and return like this.

```
+------------+----------------+----------+----------+
| date       | shop_id        | status=A | status=B |
+------------+----------------+----------+----------+
| 2016-04-01 | 121101201      | 9        |        6 |
| 2016-04-04 | 121101201      | 4        |        5 |
| 2016-04-05 | 121101201      | 11       |        3 |
```

How can I make sql query for the above output.

Thank you for your help and share.

Comment: Instant vote-up without even evidence of an attempt here?

Comment: @William: I just reversed it. Don't understand how "give me teh codez" questions get upvoted.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, and how it has not worked. Till then it is just another "give me teh codez" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  date, 
        shop_id, 
        SUM(case when status='A' then count else 0 end) AS `status=A`,
        SUM(case when status='B' then count else 0 end) AS `status=B`
FROM table_name
GROUP BY date, shop_id 
ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: Do not spoon-feed the OP. Explain how the code works, and please refrainf from posting code-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT  `date`, shop_id, 
        SUM(status='A') AS `status=A`,
        SUM(status='B') AS `status=B`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `date`, shop_id
```